# Unable to install software on running VMware in Windows 10

Tags: apt, software-installation

I tried to install `htop` using the command `apt-get install htop` and I get this output as

```
E: unable to locate package htop
```

So I try to clear off the `source.list` file in order to clear off the code inside it but it says restricted access

I just want to install some application through the terminal which I can't even after using `sudo`.

Comment: How does this relate to Ubuntu? I only see Windows and Vmware in the question.

Comment: I used the vmware in my windows 10 and when i installed ubuntu in it the process was fine and when i started using sudo option to install ssh and htop it shows me errors on my source.list and when i tried to clear off the errors it showed me restricted access.. so what do i have to in order to make the downloads possible?

Comment: do you have internet access in the virtual environment ?

Comment: Just now i checked on it and @GiorgosSaridakis I couldn't get the internet access

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the app is available for your version. See [here](https://itsfoss.com/unable-to-locate-package-error-ubuntu/).

Just type in `top` in the terminal and you will see the information you need.

However if you want `htop` then follow ahead.
First run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to keep the repository link up to date and update the apps if any.

Then run `sudo apt install htop`. This should just work fine, however if this is giving an error (as you said), try using the snap version of this package. Install the snap version using `sudo snap install htop`. However to use use snap you will need to install snap. To do this run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install snapd`.

You could also try `gnome-system-monitor` which is a GUI based application. Just open you app drawer with `super + A`, and search for `monitor` and it should just pop right up. However you could install manually with `sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor`.

To clear the `source.list` you will need sudo rights. You could run `sudo nautilus` in terminal and then the file explorer will open with sudo rights, but not all files are shown in it. So you could try the `rm` command from the terminal with sudo right to remove any file. Eg. to remove a file on desktop named `temp.txt`, I will use `sudo rm -rf /home/desktop/temp.txt`. `-rf` is used to force remove. Syntax is `sudo rm -rf /filepath/filename` to remove a file name `filename` at `filepath` location.

Comment: thank you it runs now

Comment: @shark did it run on its own or was my answer any helpful. If it was helpful upvote it and accept it (click the tick mark besides my answer).